# Program to generate batch PDFs or JPEGs?

Tags: pdf, batch, jpeg

I have a spreadsheet and I was wondering if anyone knew of a program that would batch generate simple PDFs or JPEGs from the records in it a la mail merge? That is, I have a record that contains Title, Author, Subjects, etc. and I want an image that contains the text from those fields. I would also want control over how the file is named. And then I want it done 3000 times. Does this make sense?

Comment: LibreOffice, (it comes with Ubuntu installation) can do mail merge, and save as PDF. I suppose, you can write a macro to do it 3000 times. I have no idea how, though.

Comment: From the top of my hat, it should be possible to use LibreOffice's mail merge functionality. It might not be done with two or three clicks, maybe you'd have to write a little macro or two, but it should be possible.